# What is the best way to pass values to pipeline parameters in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

How do we initialize parameter values in Azure Data Factory in a full fledged production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding parameters in Data Factory, we persist all required values in a sql server database. In our sql server table we add a column called `pipeline_name`. This will be the same name as the data factory pipeline.

When creating a pipeline in data factory we fetch the results from sql server with a copy job activity. In the copy job activity we add a `where` clause.

```
WHERE pipeline = '@{pipeline().Pipeline}'
```

Then we have our parameters to use in the pipeline which we can easily change in sql server itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Does it mean that COPY ACTIVITY can copy values from an sql query into our pipeline parameters? It sounds great, if possible, could you please help me with some more details (or referable links) about it?

Comment: With a copy activity you can query data from a SQL Server. You can then use this data as parameters in the rest of the pipeline. Here is a link: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server?tabs=data-factory

Comment: I think you mean using LOOKUP ACTIVITY here instead of COPY Activity. Because how can we use pipeline parameter as a sink for copy activity?

Comment: That is correct @vaibhavgautam. I meant a lookup activity.